# Struts2 : ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setMontant" failed for object dao.Operation@1ed5095

Tags: java, struts2, double

I have an object which need to be updated "opereation", the following form is used to update it. I have a Double attribute called Montant that created the problem, I can't update it because the form return a String and not a double value,

but when i want to update my object "operation", i found this error :

```
    Avertissement: Error setting value
    ognl.MethodFailedException: **Method "setMontant"** failed for object dao.Operation@1ed5095 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: **setMontant([Ljava.lang.String;)]**
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:823)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:964)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:75)
        at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:131)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:28)
        at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1656)
...............................
```

Form.jsp

```
    <s:form  validate="true"  namespace="/"   name="form" id="form">

   <s:select id="immatriculs" list="immatriculs" label="immatriculation" name="immatricul">
</s:select>
     <<s:textfield  id="datepicker" name="dt_debut" label="Date début :"  >
<s:textfield  id="montant" name="montant" label="Montant :">
    <s:submit action="ajouterassurance"  name="Enregistrer" value="Inserer"> </s:submit>

    </s:form>
```

pojo :

```
  public class Operation {

        private Integer idOperation;
        private Date dt_debut;
        private Double montant;
        private String immatricul;

    // setters and getters 

    public Double getMontant() 
    {
        return montant;
    }
    public void setMontant(Double montant) 
    {
        this.montant = montant;
    }

    }
```

Actionclass :

```
public class GestionOperations extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Operation>{

    private Operation operation = new Operation();

    private OperationService operationservice;

    public GestionOperations() {
        //contructor
    }



    public String add() 
    {
                operationservice = new OperationServiceImpl();
                operationservice.AddOperation(operation);

                return "success";
    }

    public String execute()
    {

        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public Operation getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return operation;
    }


}
```

I try to change "setMontant" to this :

```
public void setMontant(String montant)
{
this.monatnt = Double.parseDouble(montant);

}
```

but in this case it return `null` value,

Comment: shouldn't the return type of your setter be `void`?

Comment: ya i wrote void in my application, it was a mistake just when i was writing my question

Comment: are you using any custom interceptor? if so, you should include `modelDriven` interceptor. 
And i was looking at struts documentation, they had set the return type of `getModel()` to `Object`

Comment: I don't use any interceptor, i changed the return type but i still have the same error ?

Comment: What value are you submitting? Setter must take double not string.

Comment: I said that I tried with both cases, with Double it gives me the above error, and with String it return null values !